# Android studio clone from github issue with project iml files

Tags: git, android-studio, github, git-clone, android-project-template

I tried to clone a repo from GitHub to Android Studio using "Project from Version Control-> Github" The cloning works, but it ends up with the error shown in following figure and no Java files exist.

Errors Loading Project

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure your project modules from the repository that has been cloned.

Go to your **project setting**, choose **Dependencies** and from the right panel, choose `+` sign and then **Module Dependency**.

Then navigate to where you or the android studio have cloned the projects and choose the folders that contain the `LuckyDraw-app` and `app`.

Also, I recommend you try to clone the project using the git termianl and then create an android studio project with the **Import Existing Android Studio Project wizard.**